# Rust - Need help making code idiomatic and clean (with lifetimes)

Tags: beginner, rust

This is the first real program I have written in rust. What started as a clean piece of rust code, turned into a lifetime monstrosity when I decided to make my `enum`s and `struct`s use `&str` instead of `String`. The algorithm implemented is irrelevant; I just need help making my code more idiomatic and clean. Here is (quite simple) my code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct BasicBlock<'a> {
    block_id: u32,
    code: Vec<IRCode<'a>>,
    preds: Vec<Box<BasicBlock<'a>>>,
    succs: Vec<Box<BasicBlock<'a>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum IRCode<'a> {
    Basic {
        value: &'a str,
        btype: Type,
        id: u32,
    },
    Quadruple {
        op: Op,
        params: Vec<IRCode<'a>>,
        location: Storage<'a>,
    },
    // and some more...
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Type {
    TVarRef,
    // and some more...
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Storage<'a> {
    Temp { name: &'a str },
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Op {
    Add,
    Sub,
}

impl<'a> Hash for BasicBlock<'a> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.block_id.hash(state);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SSA<'a> {
    count: HashMap<&'a str, u32>,
    current_def: HashMap<&'a str, HashMap<Box<&'a BasicBlock<'a>>, Box<IRCode<'a>>>>,
}

impl<'a> SSA<'a> {
    fn new() -> SSA<'a> {
        SSA {
            count: HashMap::new(),
            current_def: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn new_variable(&mut self, name: &'a str, block: &'a BasicBlock<'a>) -> &Box<IRCode<'a>> {
        // If `name` is not in `count`, insert `(name, 0)`; else increment the count
        *self.count.entry(name).or_insert(0) += 1;
        self.current_def.entry(name).or_insert(HashMap::new());
        self.current_def.get_mut(&name).unwrap().insert(
            Box::new(block),
            Box::new(IRCode::Basic {
                value: name,
                btype: Type::TVarRef,
                id: *self.count.get(&name).unwrap(),
            }),
        );
        self.current_def.get(&name).unwrap().get(&block).unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // very simple test case
    let mut ssa = SSA::new();
    let bb0 = BasicBlock {
        block_id: 0,
        code: vec![],
        preds: vec![],
        succs: vec![],
    };
    println!("{:?}", ssa.new_variable("foo", &bb0));
    println!("{:?}", ssa);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why do you want to use &str instead of String in these cases? The best way of approaching this will depend on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @WinstonEwert -- I had some trouble using String (that is what I initially used). Also, I've heard `&str` is better for just looking into strings (not modifying them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello and welcome to the Rust community.

After a single read of your code, I have a couple comments.

- your problems with `&str` as well as keying by `block_id` would be best remedied by putting interners in `SSA`. The best interner choice would be [`string-interner`](https://crates.io/crates/string-interner) or [`internment`](https://crates.io/crates/internment).
- in `fn new_variable`, you have repeated lookups for the same entry of `current_def`. LLVM will be unable to optimize out repeated accesses to HashMap. This may slow us down by something like 120~200ns per invocation of the function, because one `HashMap` lookup takes approx. 40~70ns.
- you have `Vec<Box<...>>` and `HashMap<Box<...>,Box<...>>`. This inclusion of `Box` within another container immediately raises a flag in the mind of a Rust programmer that the code is not cleaned up. Wrapping in `Box` does not provide anything over wrapping in `Vec`, `HashMap` or any other container. All wraps provide unique ownership with memory indirection. To illustrate with an example, `Box<[T]>` is almost like `Vec` in that both are owned dynamic-length slices (indexable memory ranges) except that `Box<[T]>` does not allow any overprovisioning of memory (`Vec` can have capacity above length).
- the `SSA::current_def` type expression is basically as long as your average tweet. Break down complex types longer than 30-40 characters into smaller definitions.

We will begin by changing `SSA` and `fn new_variable`, with new structure `SSADef`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct SSA<'a> {
    content: HashMap<&'a str, SSADef<'a>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SSADef<'a> {
    count: u32,
    current_def: HashMap<&'a BasicBlock<'a>, IRCode<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> SSA<'a> {
    fn new() -> SSA<'a> {
        SSA { content: HashMap::new() }
    }

    fn new_variable<'s>(&'s mut self, name: &'a str, block: &'a BasicBlock<'a>) -> &'s IRCode<'a> {
        // If `name` is not in `content`, insert `SSADef::new()`
        let def = self.content.entry(name).or_insert_with(SSADef::new);
        // Increment the count
        def.count += 1;
        def.current_def.entry(block).or_insert(
            IRCode::Basic {
                value: name,
                btype: Type::TVarRef,
                id: def.count,
            }
        )
    }
}

impl<'a> SSADef<'a> {
    fn new() -> SSADef<'a> {
        SSADef {
            count: 0,
            current_def: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

One minor observation: you can derive `Default` for `SSA` and `SSADef` and call `default` from both `new`s. This will put `0`s and empty `HashMap`s and other default values in the fields of these structures.

We add the `StringInterner`. I assume the deeper functionality will always have easy access to top level `SSA`, and consequently easy access to the interner. If not, we can use some other crate such as `internment` which provides an appropriate API.

Changing the `BasicBlock`s for interning is left as an exercise for the reader. We arrive at the following code, which has very few `'a`s left. This is all I can do without knowledge of the algorithm, I believe:

````rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

use string_interner::{StringInterner, DefaultSymbol as Sym};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct BasicBlock {
    block_id: u32,
    code: Vec<IRCode>,
    preds: Vec<BasicBlock>,
    succs: Vec<BasicBlock>,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum IRCode {
    Basic {
        value: Sym,
        btype: Type,
        id: u32,
    },
    Quadruple {
        op: Op,
        params: Vec<IRCode>,
        location: Storage,
    },
    // and some more...
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Type {
    TVarRef,
    // and some more...
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Storage {
    Temp { name: Sym },
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Op {
    Add,
    Sub,
}

impl Hash for BasicBlock {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.block_id.hash(state);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct SSA<'a> {
    content: HashMap<Sym, SSADef<'a>>,
    interner: StringInterner,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct SSADef<'a> {
    count: u32,
    current_def: HashMap<&'a BasicBlock, IRCode>,
}

impl<'a> SSA<'a> {
    fn new() -> SSA<'a> {
        SSA::default()
    }

    fn new_variable<'s>(&'s mut self, name: &'a str, block: &'a BasicBlock) -> &'s IRCode {
        let name_sym = self.interner.get_or_intern(name);
        // If `name` is not in `content`, insert `SSADef::new()`
        let def = self.content.entry(name_sym).or_insert_with(SSADef::new);
        // Increment the count
        def.count += 1;
        def.current_def.entry(block).or_insert(
            IRCode::Basic {
                value: name_sym,
                btype: Type::TVarRef,
                id: def.count,
            }
        )
    }
}

impl<'a> SSADef<'a> {
    fn new() -> SSADef<'a> {
        SSADef::default()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // very simple test case
    let mut ssa = SSA::new();
    let bb0 = BasicBlock {
        block_id: 0,
        code: vec![],
        preds: vec![],
        succs: vec![],
    };
    println!("{:?}", ssa.new_variable("foo", &bb0));
    println!("{:?}", ssa);
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I was wondering if I had another `IRCode` variant that had a field that was supposed to be a reference to a `BasicBlock`, would I add a lifetime?

Comment: @xilpex you would best add `Rc<BasicBlock>` (or `Arc`) or a symbol from an interner.

Answer (score 3):

Peter Blackson has offered a lot of good points.

Here, I'll focus on one particular issue: your use of references and lifetimes. In particular, you store &str and &BasicBlock in your data structures. This is not a good idea. You should use plain String and BasicBlock.

To see why, let's make a slight change to your code:

```
 fn build_ssa() -> SSA 
    // very simple test case
    let mut ssa = SSA::new();
    let bb0 = BasicBlock {
        block_id: 0,
        code: vec![],
        preds: vec![],
        succs: vec![],
    };
    ssa.new_variable(&format!("&{}", 12), &bb0);
    ssa
}
```

You'll find that this won't work. The `bb0` BasicBlock will be destroyed at the end of the `build_ssa function`. The string created by the format macro will be destroyed at the end of that line. Both will prevent you from returning the SSA struct from this function.

That's why you most likely want to have SSA take ownership of both the `BasicBlock`s and strings. To do so, use `String` and `BasicBlock` rather than `&str` and `&BasicBlock`.

Now, you've heard that you should use `&str` when you only need to read the string and not modify it. Here, however, you want to store the string in the SSA. Functions that store values will usually need to take ownership of the value, and not merely take a reference.

Now, there is a use case for the sort of structure you did here. That's when you want to share memory between two data structures. For example, if your SSA was produced following an AST, you might want to share memory used for the strings since they probably appear in both your AST and your SSA. On the other hand, you might not, since you plausibly want to throw away your AST when you are finished with it.

Comment: *For example, if your SSA was produced following an AST* -- I'm getting the feeling you know that algo I am implementing :)

Comment: @xiipex, well there is very little other reason to be building an SSA :)